# Need help recording ultrasonic frequencies with microphone

Tags: microphone, frequency

I am working on a project; detecting the sounds made by pests in stored grain while eating. I know that the ultrasonic disturbances occur when the pests tear the materials during feeding.

I need a microphone that can detect these 'ultrasounds'. I will connect the microphone directly to a PC and carry out the frequency extraction in National Instruments' Lab-View software. I searched and found that the Panasonic wm-61a and Primo em-172 can detect ultrasonic frequencies. Can I use them? Or are there any other alternatives?

Also please elaborate if I require anything else to detect ultrasonic frequencies. I am new to this and any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that both microphones you mention do detect ultrasonic waves ? Documentation for these ( http://www.primomic.com/products/pdf/EM172.pdf , http://industrial.panasonic.com/lecs/www-data/pdf/ABA5000/ABA5000CE22.pdf ) does not says anything about what happens above 20 kHz.

Comment: i found it in this site.http://www.wildlife-sound.org/equipment/technote/micdesigns/ultrasonic.html it says that the mike can handle up to 60khz

Comment: ok, seems promising.

Comment: Can it detect the ultrasound based on that article? The insect frequencies lies between 25-45 khz. Also what does flatness of response mean? Does un-even frequency response mean it cant detect a particular frequency? I might be asking too much but i really don't know anything. Please guide me.

Comment: "Connect the microphone directly to PC" - Using the built-in PC microphone input? That input is unlikely to be able to convert frequencies above about 20 kHz. You really need an interface that has a sampling frequency of at least 96 kHz - 192 kHz would be better, plus you'll need a mic preamp that doesn't top out too soon.

Comment: Yes using microphone input of pc. as i mentioned i will be using labview for frequency processing. here is a screenshot. http://i57.tinypic.com/14qlww.png . it supports upto 96khz which i think is enough because insect frequency does not go beyond 45khz. also why do i need a pre amp and what does mic topping out mean? @Todd

Answer (score 1):

Sanken made a mic called the mo-64, some call it the insect mic.  I think its the most sensitive in that frequency range that you can find but is about $3,000

Comment: Thats too costly. can i add a circuit may be to make the mics i mentioned more  sensitive?(noob here so apologies if this sounds stupid). also i found the mic can handle ultrasound here http://www.wildlife-sound.org/equipment/technote/micdesigns/ultrasonic.html

Answer (score 1):

This B&K measurement mic goes up to 140 kHz. http://www.bksv.com/Products/transducers/acoustic/microphones/microphone-cartridges/4138

Answer (score 1):

I've not used one before, but have been thinking about getting one of these Dodotronic USB ultrasonic mics:

http://www.dodotronic.com/index.php/ultramics/

I'd love to hear any feedback from anyone who has used one.