# Best ultrasonic microphone for recording mouse squeaks?

Tags: microphone, high-frequency

I need to record mice squeaks which range from 20 - 100 kHz.  Are there any good American-made alternatives to the co-100k?  https://www.sankenchromatic.com/products/co-100k/

I'm not a sound technician/specialist, so plug and play options are preferred.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic… but what do you consider to be "plug and play" when choosing a microphone? Plug into what, play through what?

Comment: Thank you for responding to my off-topic question - I am truly a n00b.  It would be nice if I could plug the microphone directly into my acquisition computer.  The recording will be analyzed with Deep Squeak - a deep learning system that identifies and classifies squeak patterns: https://github.com/DrCoffey/DeepSqueak

Comment: You're going to need a mic preamp > USB specifically designed to match the mic's input capabilities. Regular  audio devices only go up to human audio range, 20kHz. approx. I found this too - https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/35771/need-help-recording-ultrasonic-frequencies-with-microphone

Comment: As Tetsujin said, recommendations are offtopic, but I closed as a dupe of the most useful question on this.